# CloudCraze make Order and Order_Terms

Tags: cloudcraze

In cloudCraze I am trying to locate the service making this query.
`(Select Id, IsDeleted, Name, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, Order__c, Description__c, Title__c From OrderTerms__r)`, that populates the object CC_Order_Terms

When the product order is created, this object is generated:

```
 "orderTermsS": 
                  {
                      "order": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      "sfid": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      "isDeleted": false,
                      "sfdcName": "00018",
                      "createdDate": 1600777075000,
                      "createdById": "0059E000009Kl39QAC",
                      "lastModifiedDate": 1600777075000,
                      "lastModifiedById": "0059E000009Kl39QAC",
                      "systemModstamp": 1600777075000,
                      "description": "test descrizione term condition 0002",
                      "title": "titolo terms 00002"
                    }
```

My goal is to add a custom field in query and in this object (orderTermsS).

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Creation Order and Order\_Terms with custom field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320396/creation-order-and-order-terms-with-custom-field)

Comment: When you have a question closed, re-asking the exact same question again is just going to make the community frustrated. Your previous question was closed because it didn't contain enough details. [Edit] your question to include more details.